# MemoryError of Python Module dbf

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dbf

I would like to conver a csv to dbf in python by the following way:

```
import dbf
table = dbf.from_csv('/home/beata/Documents/NC/CNRM_control/CNRM_pr_power1961','CNRM_pr_power1961.dbf')
```

but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbf/__init__.py", line 172, in from_csv
    mtable.append(tuple(row))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbf/tables.py", line 1154, in append
    newrecord[index] = item
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbf/tables.py", line 278, in __setitem__
    yo.__setattr__(yo._layout.fields[name], value)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbf/tables.py", line 269, in __setattr__
    yo._updateFieldValue(fielddef, value)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbf/tables.py", line 168, in _updateFieldValue
    bytes = array('c', update(value, fielddef, yo._layout.memo))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbf/_io.py", line 132, in updateMemo
    block = memo.put_memo(string)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dbf/tables.py", line 424, in put_memo
    yo.memory[thismemo] = data
MemoryError
>>>
```

The size of csv is 2.4 GiB. My ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS type is 64-bit with 31.3 GiB memory and Intel Xeon(R) CPU ES-1660vz@ 3.70GHz x12

Could someone write me what I should to do to fix this error?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have there is that `dbf.from_csv` attempts to create an in-memory table, and your O/S isn't letting you have enough RAM to do so.

To get around that problem I re-wrote `from_csv` to write directly to disk if you pass `on_disk=True`.  Check out [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) for the latest code.

The remaining problem is in the dbf format itself -- you may run into problems with files that large as the internal structure wasn't designed for such large capacities.  If the update doesn't completely solve your problem you'll need to split your csv file and create multiple dbfs out of it.

Feel free to email me directly if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I accepted your suggestion and I split the file to smaller (yearly data) parts. So one smaller part is about 450 MB and python-dbf module can convert it during 25 min.